# Set off an Event in case any one of a group of radiobutton gets checkchanged

Tags: c#

Situation is as follows:

I have a ButtonA, which is currently not enabled.
I have 5 Radiobuttons of which one is always checked.

I want to enable ButtonA when a different Radiobutton gets selected.

I thought about doing something like

```
private void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ButtonA.Enabled = true;
}

private void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ButtonA.Enabled = true;
}
```

... and so on.

There is probably a more elegant solution and im missing it.

Comment: No, that's pretty much the simplest you can get.

Comment: why dont you go for a radio button list instead

Comment: You could make all the radio buttons use the same event hander, then you don't need to repeat the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single method as an event handler for all radiobuttons:

```
private void RadioButtonChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonA.Enabled = true;
}

private void HandleEvents()
{
    this.RadioButton1.CheckedChanged += RadioButtonChanged;
    this.RadioButton2.CheckedChanged += RadioButtonChanged;
    this.RadioButton3.CheckedChanged += RadioButtonChanged;
}
```

Or a loop to do the same thing:

```
private void RadioButtonChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonA.Enabled = true;
}

private void HandleEvents()
{
    foreach(var rb in new[] {RadioButton1, RadioButton2, RadioButton3})
        rb.CheckedChanged += RadioButtonChanged;
}
```

Or even a lambda event handler set in a loop:

```
private void HandleEvents()
{
    foreach(var rb in new[] {RadioButton1, RadioButton2, RadioButton3})
        rb.CheckedChanged += (o,e) => ButtonA.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: thank you, havent really gone as far as eventhandlers yet. Ill try to read up as soon as i can. after the += RadioButtonChanged, wouldnt you add (sender, e); there?

Answer (score 0):

How about just having 1 event handler like this:

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonA.Enabled = true;
}
```

Then you can use the form designer to assign this method name to the CheckedChanged events of all the radio buttons.

This will save you having to repeat the code for each radio button.

Another trick is to add all your radio buttons to a group box or panel in the designer, then they will all be children of that control.

Then you can add the following code to your Load event handler for the form:

```
foreach(var radioButton in radioGroupBox.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                                        .Where(i => i is RadioButton)
                                        .Cast<RadioButton>())
{
    radioButton.CheckedChanged += RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
}
```

This way, if you add more RadioButtons to the group, you don't need to change any code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Im really new to c# so ill try to get your first method working.

Comment: No problem. The second solution uses the code from the first, but just means you don't have to go to the designer and change things if you're adding more radio buttons. But if you plan to stick with just the 5, there's no harm in just adding that handler 5 times in the designer.